# Why LoadLibrary() fail's on libvlc.dll when I changed the target framework in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, libvlc, onvif

I encountered an strange problem in c#...
I was trying to connect to an ONVIF camera through VLC library(tell me if there's a better way)
And I found a nice pre-implemented library called nVLC on the NuGet, then I used it, and it was very good,
But when I changed the target framework in c# I realized that nVLC's target framework is different from the one I selected,
And when I changed the target framework back to 4.0(As nVLC's) I've got a strange LibVlcInitException exception,
Then I downloaded the nVLC source code and debug database as well to find out what is wrong in the nVLC
Finally I found that the exception is not in the nVLC's code but somewhere in C# internal
library loading mechanism that handles extern methods.
I even tried to load the libvlc.dll using kernel method LoadLibrary() in my project but this
one failed like before...

```
m_hMediaLib = LibVlcMethods.libvlc_new(args.Length, args); //nVLC internal line that error occures.
//and:
IMediaPlayerFactory _factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(); //in my code.
```

I prefer to use VLC to connect to my ONVIF camera(my camera give me a H264 format).

finally:

1. I want to know what's the problem with LoadLibrary().
2. I want to know if there's a better library to connect to an ONVIF camera with less code(JUST H264).

Thank you...

Comment: Did the bitness of your process change somehow?

Comment: No! even occures when I rebuild the project.

Comment: What are the details of the error??

Comment: this one on nVLC:Failed to initialize libVLC. Possible reasons : Some of the arguments may be incorrect. VLC dlls' version mismatch.

Comment: wait to get error on LoadLibrary().

Comment: When LoadLibrary return 0 also Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 0 !!

Comment: How about rebuilding your project from scratch using the right framework version? It might be easier than trying to troubleshoot a weird error version mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a hard working week!!
This is because of nVLC's way to find the VLC installation path...

If you have installed a x64 VLC this will add a key named "SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC" into the registery for sure.
Then in the nVLC it check for process(Environment.Is64BitProcess) if it is x64 get the VLC installation path from "SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC" (the one I missing because I installed x86 version of VLC) but if process is x86 it search in "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" for VLC.

Hope help you...